# Primefaces spinner max attribute reach to reset value

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

In Spinner I use min and max attribute.In min=0 and max=59.When I click spinner it will increment value to show my doubt when its reach max value again click not increment that the situation it will again start min value.It possible?

Answer (score 2):

Using ajax is a way:

In your page:

```
<h:form id="form">

    <p:spinner min="0" max="60" value="#{yourBean.cuenta}"  onkeypress="return false">
        <p:ajax process="@this" update="@this" listener="#{yourBean.cuentaF}"/>
    </p:spinner>

</h:form>
```

In your backing bean:

```
private Integer cuenta;

public void cuentaF(){
    if(this.cuenta>59)
        this.cuenta = 0;
}

public Integer getCuenta() {
    return cuenta;
}  
public void setCuenta(Integer cuenta) {
    this.cuenta = cuenta;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Using jQuery is another way:

In your page:

```
<h:body>
<!-- THE SCRIPT -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

        var previous = -1;
        var $htmlvalue = $('#form\\:jss .ui-spinner-input');
        var $uparrow = $('#form\\:jss .ui-spinner-up');
        var $downarrow = $('#form\\:jss .ui-spinner-down');
        $htmlvalue.val(0);
        PF('vjss').value=0;

        $uparrow.click(function(){

            var limit = PF('vjss').value == previous;               

            if(PF('vjss').value==59 &amp;&amp; limit){
                PF('vjss').value=0; 
                $htmlvalue.val(0);
            }
            previous = PF('vjss').value;
            });

        $downarrow.click(function(){

            var limit = PF('vjss').value == previous;

            if(PF('vjss').value==0 &amp;&amp; limit){
                PF('vjss').value=59; 
                $htmlvalue.val(59);
            }               
            previous = PF('vjss').value;
            });         
  });       
</script>

<!-- THE JSF SPINNER COMPONENT -->
<h:form id="form">
    <p:spinner widgetVar="vjss" id="jss" min="0" max="59" value="#{yourBean.cuenta}"/>
</h:form>
</h:body>
```

In your backing bean:

```
private Integer cuenta;    
public Integer getCuenta() {
    return cuenta;
}
public void setCuenta(Integer cuenta) {
    this.cuenta = cuenta;
}
```

Comment: It possible handle javaScript becuase I allow key event and try to reduce backbean event

Comment: I edited the initial solution. Did you try the second solution? It is a client side solution implemented in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution to @lametaweb but without altering MAX and MIN values. With these both solution you barely add little coding to your BackBean.

In your page:

```
<p:spinner id="ajaxSpinner" min="0" max="59" value="#{yourBean.number}">
    <p:ajax update="@this" process="@this" />
</p:spinner>
```

And in your BackingBean:

```
private static final int MAX=59;
private static final int MIN=0;
private int number;

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(int number) {

    if (this.number == MAX && number + 1 > MAX){
        this.number = MIN;
    }else if (this.number == MIN && number -1 < MIN){
        this.number=MAX;
    }else{
        this.number=number;
    }
}
```